# Azure File Copy Fails

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have this task in Devops: I want to copy a text file from blobstorage to a VM.

```
- task: AzureFileCopy@4
      inputs:
        sourcePath: 'https://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/container/file.txt'
        azureSubscription: 'subscription connection'
        storage: 'a_storage_in_subscription'
        resourceGroup: $(rgName_of_VM)
        destination: 'azureVMs'
        MachineNames: $(ipofVM)
        vmsAdminUserName: $(adminUsername)
        vmsAdminPassword: $(adminPassword)
        targetPath: 'c:\files'
```

But it fails with `Upload to container: '8e107770-69d8-xxx' in storage account: 'a_storage_in_subscription' with blob prefix: '' failed with error: 'AzCopy.exe exited with non-zero exit code while uploading files to blob storage.' For more info please refer to https://aka.ms/azurefilecopyreadme`

My understanding is that the task copies the file and first puts it in a container in the 'storage' field (a guid is used to create it). The task succeeded in it but then error happened. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May I know what's the status of this after the weekend?

Comment: The reason for this is your blob container do net have Access control (AIM)  permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you re-run this failed pipeline along with setting `system.debug` to `true`, you will see another message which can explain more detailed for why it failed: `failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to error: cannot scan the path \\?\D:\a\1\s\https://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/container/file.txt`.

Now, you should know that why you encountered that error message. That's because our `Azure File Copy` task does not support to use HTTPS url in `sourcePath`. The value of `sourcePath` must satisfied on below mentioned:

[image]

---

Since we does not support to use HTTPS url here. As a work around, you can firstly [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download) this file into build working directory firstly by using `Azure cli` command. Then upload it to `AzureVM`:

```
- task: AzureCLI@1
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: {subscription}
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     mkdir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/File
     az storage blob download --container-name {container name} --file $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/file --name {file name} --account-key $(accountkey) --account-name {blob name} 

- task: AzureFileCopy@4
  displayName: 'AzureVMs File Copy'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/File'
    azureSubscription: {subscription}
    Destination: AzureVMs
    storage: {storage}
    resourceGroup: '{resource group}'
    vmsAdminUserName: {login name}
    vmsAdminPassword: {login password}
    TargetPath: 'xxx'
```

**Note**: You can get the `accesskey` from this tab:

[image]

Now, you can see that you can succeed to upload file to AzureVM.

Comment: could not test it as my hosted agent did not have CLI installed. will get back shortly